# Minimum of the Gamma Function $\Gamma (x)$ for $x>0$. How to find $x_{\min}$?

Tags: calculus, approximation, gamma-function, numerical-methods, special-functions

The $\Gamma (x)$ function has just one minimum for $x>0$ . This result uses some
properties of the gamma function:

- $\Gamma ^{\prime \prime }(x)>0$ and $\Gamma (x)>0$ for all $x>0$
- $\Gamma (1)=\Gamma (2)=1$.

Observing the following graph (created in SWP) of $y=\Gamma (x)$ this minimum is near $x=3/2$, but likely $\min \Gamma (x)\neq \Gamma \left( 3/2\right) =\dfrac{1}{2}\Gamma \left( 1/2\right) =\dfrac{1}{2}\sqrt{\pi }$.

[image]

I think that it is not possible to find analytically the exact value of $x_{\min }$, even by converting to an adequate problem in the interval $]0,1]$ and using the functional equation $\Gamma (x+1)=x\Gamma (x)$ and the reflection formula

$\Gamma (p)\Gamma (p-1)=\dfrac{\pi }{\sin px}\qquad $( $0\lt p\lt 1$)

**Question:**

a) Which is the best way to find $\min_{[1,2]}\Gamma (x)$ and does $x_{\min }$ lay in $[1,3/2]$ or in $[3/2,2]$?

b) Is there some useful series expansion of $\Gamma (x)$?

c) Which numeric method do you suggest?

---

**Edit:**  Due to the shape of $\Gamma (x)$ I thought on the one-dimensional [Davies-Swann-Campey](http://ntu-cg.ntu.edu.sg/ysong/conference/MemeticGradientSearch.pdf) method of direct search for unconstrained optimization, which approximates a function near a minimum by successive approximating quadratic polynomials.

Comment: A general rule of thumb in numerical computing: it's easier to compute (simple) roots of functions to the full precision of your environment than to compute extrema.

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=min+Gamma%28x%29+from+0+to+3

Comment: computation results in 1935 http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v135/n3422/abs/135917b0.html

Comment: So as it's not simple to compute the value analytically, it's worth stating that $\left(\frac{33}{20}\cdot\frac{\pi^4}{110}\ ,\ \frac{\pi^4}{110}\right)$ is an approximation to  $(x,y)_{\text{min}}$ with an error of $\mathcal{O}(10^{-4})$ in the first and even less in the second variable.

Comment: The [OEIS sequence A030169](https://oeis.org/A030169) is "Decimal expansion of real number x such that y = Gamma(x) is a minimum." and its entry has computer code to compute it.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici It seems there is a very strange  series for that see : $$f\left(x\right)=\frac{1}{3}\frac{1}{\sin\left(x\right)\left(1-\sqrt{x}\right)+1}+\frac{2}{3}\left(\frac{1}{\sin\left(x\right)\left(1-x\right)+1}\right)^{\frac{3}{5}}+\frac{1}{1400}\left(1-\sqrt{1+x\left(1-x\right)}\right),|f'\left(0.461632144\right)|<5\cdot10^{-7}$$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici see $$f(x)=\frac{1}{\ln(e/2+\pi/2)(x!+1/x!)}-x$$ amazing no ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There indeed is no closed-form for the gamma function's minimum; what you can do instead, however, is to find the positive root of the digamma function (the logarithmic derivative of the gamma function), which should be available in your computing environment.

Comment: For instance, the computation in *Mathematica* goes something like `x /. FindRoot[PolyGamma[x], {x, 1}, WorkingPrecision -> 20]` which yields the result 1.4616321449683623413 .

Comment: Thanks, you have answered to a), b) and confirmed that it is not possible to find analytically the gamma function's minimum! Since I have no access to *Mathematica* I will try to use PARI.

Comment: Américo: As for question b.), there are series expansions (see DLMF for instance), but none of them seem to be practical so I'd steer away from them. I believe PARI/GP has a digamma/polygamma function somewhere, just check the docs.

Comment: @Mangaldan: I will check. Also I intend to study further the subject of series expansions for the present situation.

Comment: I'm actually trying to *discourage* you from looking at the series expansions (well okay, let's make an exception for Stirling); but if you think you can glean new insights, dig in: http://dlmf.nist.gov/5.7

Comment: I see your point. Just to feel it by myself, now that I have your information and advice.

Comment: Does that minimum (x or y) have a name?

Comment: @Heimdall, I do not believe it has been named, but I would be happy to be proven wrong.

Answer (score 14):

You have
$$\frac d {dx} \Gamma(x)=\Gamma (x)\, \psi (x)$$ Knowing that the solution is close to $\frac 32$, make a Taylor expansion around this value. This would give
$$y=\psi (x)=\psi^{(0)} \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)+\left(\frac{\pi ^2}{2}-4\right)
   \left(x-\frac{3}{2}\right)+\frac{1}{2}  \psi
   ^{(2)}\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)\left(x-\frac{3}{2}\right)^2+O\left(\left(x-\frac{3}{2}\right)^3\right)$$ Now, using series reversion
$$x=\frac{3}{2}+t-\frac{ \psi ^{(2)}\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)}{\pi
   ^2-8}t^2+O\left(t^3\right)\qquad \text{where} \qquad t=\frac{y-\psi ^{(0)}\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)}{\frac{\pi ^2}{2}-4}$$ Making $y=0$  gives $t=-\frac{2 (2-\gamma -2 \log (2))}{\pi ^2-8}$ leading to the estimate
$$x\sim\frac 32 +\frac{2(\gamma +2 \log (2)-2)}{\left(\pi ^2-8\right)^3} A$$ where
$$A=28 \zeta (3) (\gamma +2 \log (2)-2)+128-32 \gamma -16 \pi ^2+\pi ^4-64 \log (2)$$
$$x \approx 1.461632068$$ while the "exact" solution is $1.461632145$.

Answer (score 5):

According to [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GammaFunction.html) the minimum of the Gamma function for positive $x$ is 1.46163...; in particular I guess this is enough to deduce that it is smaller than $3/2$. You can follow the links along to find some references where this is proved.

Comment: Yes, it is enough. Thanks! In this case I have not checked before in MathWorld, although usualy I search many things there.

Answer (score 4):

Looking for the zero of the digamma function, let $x_0=\frac 32$  and use the $\color{red}{\text{first iteration}}$ of Newton-like methods of order $n$.
The obtained expression of  $x_1$ is $\color{red}{\text{fully explicit}}$.

Converted to decimals
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
n & \text{first iterate for order } n & \text{method} \\
 2 & \color{red}{1.46}09650320064341086 & \text{Newton}   \\
 3  &\color{red}{1.46162}90121170218466 & \text{Halley}   \\
 4  &\color{red}{1.4616321}028515388221 & \text{Householder}   \\
 5  &\color{red}{1.461632144}2852193151 & \text{no name}   \\
 6  &\color{red}{1.4616321449}563980751 & \text{no name}   \\
 7  &\color{red}{1.461632144968}1447118 & \text{no name}   \\
 8  &\color{red}{1.4616321449683}583003 & \text{no name}   \\
 9  &\color{red}{1.461632144968362}2653 & \text{no name}   \\
 10 &\color{red}{1.4616321449683623}398 & \text{no name}   \\
 \cdots&\cdots& \cdots \\
\infty& \color{red}{ 1.4616321449683623413} & \text{solution} \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Answer (score 4):

By [Lagrange inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_inversion_theorem) theorem on the series definition of [Digamma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function) function
$$\psi^{-1}(z)=\frac32+\frac{2}{\pi^2-8}(z-2+\gamma+\ln4)+\frac{8(7\zeta(3)-8)}{(\pi^2-8)^3}(z-2+\gamma+\ln4)^2+\left(\frac{64(7\zeta(3)-8)^3}{(\pi^2-8)^5}-\frac{8(\pi^2-96)}{3(\pi^2-8)^4}\right)(z-2+\gamma+\ln4)^3+\left(\frac{640(7\zeta(3)-8)^3}{(\pi^2-8)^7}+\frac{160(7\zeta(3)-8)(\pi^4-96)}{3(\pi^2-8)^6}+\frac{32(31\zeta(5)-32)}{(\pi^2-8)^5}\right)(z-2+\gamma+\ln4)^4+....$$
Hence, $x_{\min}=\psi^{-1}(0)\approx 1.4616321$ thanks [to WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%283%2F2%29-2*%280.03649%29%2F%28pi%5E2-8%29%2B8*%287*zeta%283%29-8%29*%280.03649%29%5E2%2F%28pi%5E2-8%29%5E3-%2864*%288-7*zeta%283%29%29%5E2%2F%28pi%5E2-8%29%5E5-%2816%2F6%29*%28pi%5E4-96%29%2F%28pi%5E2-8%29%5E4%29*%280.03649%29%5E3%2B1.0055578*%280.03649%29%5E4%2F24).

Answer (score 1):

Similar to @ClaudeLeibovici :

Define $0<x<1$:

$$f\left(x\right)=\left(\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-y^{2}}dy-x!\right)$$

Then $f(x_1)=0,f(0.5)=0$ now take the arithmetic mean of $x_1,0.5$ and before use Newton's method to evaluate $x_1$ with as starting value $\sqrt{2}-1$ with some iterations and proceed the same further. Now we have the $x_{min}$ .

Answer (score 1):

Too long for a comment  :I have a start of a series for the minimum of the Gamma function :

Let $x>0$ consider :

$$f\left(x\right)=\frac{1}{3}\cdot\frac{1}{\sin\left(x\right)\left(1-\sqrt{x}\right)+1}+\frac{2}{3}\left(\frac{1}{\sin\left(x\right)\left(1-x\right)+1}\right)^{\frac{3}{5}}+\frac{1}{1400}\left(1-\sqrt{1+x\left(1-x\right)}\right)-\frac{1}{19000}\left(1-\sqrt{1+x\left(1-x\right)}\right)^{2}$$

Then :

$$f'\left(0.461632144\right)<8*10^{-9}$$

Now define :

$F\left(x\right)=\frac{1}{3}\cdot\frac{1}{\sin\left(x\right)\left(1-\sqrt{x}\right)+1}+\frac{2}{3}\left(\frac{1}{\sin\left(x\right)\left(1-x\right)+1}\right)^{\frac{3}{5}}+\frac{1}{1400}\left(1-\sqrt{1+x\left(1-x\right)}\right)-\frac{1}{19000}\left(1-\sqrt{1+x\left(1-x\right)}\right)^{2}+\cdots+a_n\left(1-\sqrt{1+x\left(1-x\right)}\right)^{n}+\cdots$

Then it seems there exists $a_n\in(-\infty,\infty)$ such that (denotes $y=0.4616$ the minima of the factorial function over the postive real axis)

$$F'(y)=0$$

Edit :

Compare $f(x)$ with $x\in(0,1)$ :

$$h\left(x\right)=\sqrt{\frac{x!}{\left(2-x!!\right)^{2}\left(2-x!!!\right)^{2}\left(2-x!!!!\right)^{2}\left(2-x!!!!!\right)^{2}\cdot\cdot\cdot}}$$

Where $\Gamma(x+1)=x!,\Gamma(1+\Gamma(x+1))=x!!,\cdots$