# Irrationality of $\min$ and $\arg\,\min$ of $\Gamma|_{[1, 2]}$

Tags: reference-request, gamma-function, rationality-testing

The Gamma function [achieves a local minimum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particular_values_of_the_Gamma_function#Other_constants) at $x^* \approx 1.46163$, where $\Gamma(x^*) \approx 0.88560$.

Can $x^*$ and $\Gamma(x^*)$ easily be proven irrational? Are they transcendental?

Comment: Possibly related (about the minimum of the gamma function, not about irrationality): http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3245/

Comment: These are open problems, and not easy.

Comment: @JohnM: Can you cite a source?