# Relevance of the Gamma Function's local minimum at $x\approx 1.4616$

Tags: gamma-function

I've recently discovered the Gamma Function. Upon graphing it in [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator), I found something interesting: the minimum isn't at $x=0$, it's at $x\approx 1.4616$, with the value of $\Gamma(x)\approx 0.8856$. After some research [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3245/minimum-of-the-gamma-function-gamma-x-for-x0-how-to-find-x-min) and on a forum from 2012 [here](http://wrongplanet.net/forums/viewtopic.php?t=217584), I've discovered that these numbers may or may not be irrational. However, something I can't seem to find is if either of these constant shows up anywhere else, like the golden ratio and $\pi$ do.

So what I'm asking is:

- Why is the minimum of the gamma function this pair of numbers, and
- do they appear anywhere else?

Comment: As far as I know, the local minimum (or the corresponding zero of the digamma function) has no special significance outside this context.

Comment: see (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1790371) and also (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3245)

Comment: @JeanMarie Funnily enough, I came across both of those trying to find an answer.

Comment: Putting $1.461632144968362341$ into the ISC we get a match!  But the description is simply "minimal x of GAMMA(x)" ... so even they do not know another description for it.  (ISC = http://isc.carma.newcastle.edu.au)

Comment: @GEdgar Huh... maybe it really is unconnected from pretty much everything else. Note, however, that fibonacci spirals often appear on things like pinecones, but "pinecone spirals" isn't a mathematical relationship or even a specific value, so it wouldn't show up there.

Comment: Yes, it looks de-cone-cted.