# How to show that $(ex)^{-1}\leq \Gamma (x) \leq 1+1/x$, if $0<x<1$?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, exponential-function, gamma-function, upper-lower-bounds

We can use the fact that $\Gamma(x) =\frac{\Gamma (x+1) }{x}$. Suppose $e^{-1}\leq \Gamma (x) \leq x$, if $1<x<2$, then the required inequality can be proven. But is that inequality true? How to prove that?

Comment: This inequality is certainly not true. As $x \to 0^+$ the left hand inequality diverges to $+\infty$ but the right hand inequality converges to 1.

Comment: Oops I edited now

Comment: Are you sure you want $\Gamma (x) \leq 1+1/x$? Note that even the harder ineq. $\Gamma (x) \leq 1/x$ is true, see here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2205771/gamma-function-inequality-gammax-le-frac1x?rq=1

Comment: Yes that's what given in book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An upper bound has been proven [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2205771/42969): $\Gamma(x) < 1$ for $1 < x < 2$ follows from the convexity of the Gamma function, and therefore is
$$
 \Gamma(x) \le \frac 1 x \text{ for } 0 < x < 1 \, .
$$

A simple lower bound can be obtained from the integral representation: For $1 < x < 2$ is
$$
\Gamma(x) = \int_0^\infty t^{x-1} e^{-x} \, dx \ge \int_1^\infty t^{x-1} e^{-x} \, dx \\
\ge \int_1^\infty  e^{-x} \, dx = \frac 1e 
$$
and therefore
$$
 \Gamma(x) \ge \frac 1 {ex} \text{ for } 0 < x < 1 \, .
$$

(That is a very rough estimate. The [minimal value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#Minima) of the Gamma function is $\approx 0.8856$.)