# What is the nature of the the real number $x_0$ where $\Gamma(x_0)$ is minimum?

Tags: gamma-function

$\Gamma(x)$ is said to have a minimum around $x_0\approx 1.46$. Is it known that $x_0$ is an irrational number? A transcendental number for that matter? Can $x_0$ be expressed in terms of more familiar constants, like $e$ or $\pi$ ? What kind of number is $x_0$ exactly? Information on these questions seems curiously scarce even in the internet.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Minimum of the Gamma Function $\Gamma (x)$ for $x\gt;0$. How to find $x_{\min}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3245/minimum-of-the-gamma-function-gamma-x-for-x0-how-to-find-x-min)

Comment: @John B Not really...